# PHP 7.0 get_magic_quotes_runtime error

Tags: php

I have code like that:

```
    if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_runtime')) {
        $mqr = @get_magic_quotes_runtime();
        @set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);
    }
```

And when it is executed It returns error message: `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function set_magic_quotes_runtime()`

But why `function_exists('get_magic_quotes_runtime')` returns `true`?
Is it normal for PHP 7.0?

Comment: Since this function is depracted as of PHP 5.3, use `ini_set('magic_quotes_runtime', 0);` instead.

Comment: [`set` is not `get`...](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-magic-quotes-runtime.php)

Comment: @PeeHaa Though so too at first, but the OP is well aware of the difference...

Comment: @arkascha I have no idea where you see that OP is aware of that. Anyway it's a RTFM question.

Comment: @PeeHaa Because the code the OP posted has been copied&pasted from some internet "HowTo". You can find it all over the place. It checks (used to check) if some values was actually set and only the overwrites it.

Answer (score 7):

[`get_magic_quotes_runtime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-runtime.php) has returned false since PHP 5.4, was marked deprecated in 7.4, and was removed from the language in 8.0

[`set_magic_quotes_runtime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-magic-quotes-runtime.php) has been deprecated since 5.3, and was removed from the language in 7.0.

In short, you <s>probably</s> absolutely shouldn't have the words "magic quotes" anywhere in your code any more, they haven't had any functional effect in roughly a decade.

Answer (score 2):

**Change all**

`set_XXXX` functions like `set_magic_quotes_runtime`

to

`ini_set('magic_quotes_runtime', 0);`

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the error relates to `set_magic_quotes_runtime`, not `get_magic_quotes_runtime` function.

[`get_magic_quotes_runtime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-runtime.php) still exists in PHP7 but [`set_magic_quotes_runtime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-magic-quotes-runtime.php) was removed in 7.0.

Comment: "[get_magic_quotes_runtime] function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.4.0, and REMOVED as of PHP 8.0.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged."